# Modifying File-ACL in Lazarus / Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, acl, lazarus

I'm trying to get a function working in Lazarus that should add a File-ACL to the yet existing ACL of that object. Obviously I'm doing somethinh wrong: The program crashes with a SIGSEGV when it reaches BuildExplicitAccessWithName. Regarding the debugger, this function calls BuildTrusteeWithObjectsAndName iternally which then leads to the SIGSEGV.
What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code:

```
program acltest;

uses JwaWindows;

function AddFileACL(Filename, TrusteeName: AnsiString; AccessMode: ACCESS_MODE; Inheritance: dWord): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  pExplicitAccess : PEXPLICIT_ACCESS;
  ExistingDacl : PACL;
  pExistingDacl : PPACL;
  NewAcl : PACL;
  psd : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
  NewAcl := nil;
  psd := nil;
  pExistingDacl := nil;
  Result := false;
  try
    if ERROR_SUCCESS = GetNamedSecurityInfo(pAnsiChar(Filename), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, pExistingDacl, nil, psd) then
    begin
      try
        BuildExplicitAccessWithName(pExplicitAccess, PAnsiChar(TrusteeName), GENERIC_ALL, AccessMode, Inheritance);
        ExistingDacl := pExistingDacl^;
        if ERROR_SUCCESS = SetEntriesInAcl(1, pExplicitAccess, ExistingDacl, NewAcl) then
        begin
          if ERROR_SUCCESS = SetNamedSecurityInfo(pAnsiChar(Filename), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, NewAcl, nil) then
          begin
            Result := true;
          end;
        end;
      finally
      end;
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;

begin
  if AddFileACL('C:\Users\keckc\Desktop\test.txt', 'Everyone', GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT) = true then
  begin
    writeln('Yep, it works!');
  end
  else begin
    writeln('Nope, try again!');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Your use of `try...finally` looks quite pointless. Also, the last `if...then` could be converted to plain assignment statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, they are a bit pointless ATM. I will improve the error handling as soon as I have resolved the other problems ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `pExplicitAccess` which is an uninitialized pointer variable of type `PEXPLICIT_ACCESS`. You are expected instead to allocate an `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` structure, and pass its address.

```
var
  ExplicitAccess: EXPLICIT_ACCESS;
....
BuildExplicitAccessWithName(@ExplicitAccess, ...);
```

In the call to `GetNamedSecurityInfo`, passing `psd` is somewhat pointless. Since it has the value `nil`, you may as well delete pass `nil`. At which point you'll be able to remove the `psd` variable.

As for `pExistingDacl`, again you initialise it to `nil`. And so `pExistingDacl^` is going to be another SIGSEV. Instead you should remove the `pExistingDacl` variable, and pass `@ExistingDacl`.

It would seem that you have similar problems with the calls to `SetEntriesInAcl` and `SetNamedSecurityInfo`, but hopefully by now, you can understand the pattern and will be able to resolve the problems.

Finally, I do also wonder why you are using the ANSI version of the function rather than the Unicode version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have fixed the parameters as you advised. psd is needed here, even if it is not used since it's a mandatory parameter in the function. However, it still refuses to work. I've updates my source to reflect the changes. When I run it, it complains about a "wrong parameter" in SetEntriesInAcl.

Comment: You asked about the SIGSEV. Did I not answer that? Or do you want me to answer the new question too? Or, to put it another way, perhaps you would be better asking a new question about the new problem.  ;-)  Not least because I personally am not an expert in the ins and outs of the security APIs and so whilst I could answer the SIGSEV question, I'm surely the wrong person to answer the new question.

Comment: Well, yes, I asked why I got a SIGSEGV and yes, you answered that question. Thank you very much. But still I can't get that damned thing running, so it would be great if you could help me with that problem, too.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that you edited you last comment while I was typing ;-) I think I'll edit my question then in that way that it reflects the "new problem", too. Anyway thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Honestly, that's not my area of expertise. If I were you I'd ask a new question. I really don't think you should ask the new question here. Make a new question for it. Please.

Answer (score 0):

In XE8 and most likely other flavors of Delphi GetNamedSecurityInfo is declared wrong.

Two ways to solve that:

1) Redeclare as:

```
   function FixedGetNamedSecurityInfo(pObjectName: LPWSTR; ObjectType: SE_OBJECT_TYPE;
         SecurityInfo: SECURITY_INFORMATION; ppsidOwner, ppsidGroup: PPSID; ppDacl, ppSacl: PPACL;
         var ppSecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR): DWORD; stdcall;
         external 'ADVAPI32.DLL' name 'GetNamedSecurityInfoW';
```

The other is to typecast the pointer used:

```
GetNamedSecurityInfo(FileObject.ToPchar, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, PACL(@pExistingDacl), nil, pSD);
```